# Xcode 9 Version editor - Sticky scrolling

Tags: xcode, xcode9

When I try to scroll in Xcode 9's Version editor with touchpad gestures, it "sticks" to the current change in the file. This GIF illustrates the problem:

[image: Xcode 9 - Sticky scrolling]

When I drag the scrollbar, it scrolls fine that way.

Is there a method to fix this behavior?

Comment: It is not sticking intentionally, it is just another bug introduced with Xcode 9's new scrolling/paging system. I already reported it, they said it is fixed in 9.2 and closed the issue. But checked today. Nothing changed. Still buggy.

Comment: The problem still persists in Xcode 10